# MVC 5 c# hide url parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```js
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("SignInUp")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ email_add: email_add ,}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                
                if (response.result == 'SignUp') {
                    alert("Opp`s its look like you dont have an access for this website");
                    window.location = response.Urls;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Success fully login");
                    window.location = response.Url;
                }

            }
        });
```

hi guys I`m new in mvc5 c# and i in counter this problem i want to hide my url parameter. any can help me thank you for advance

this is my code:

```
public ActionResult SingInUp(string email_add)
{
    bool obj = db.tblUsers.Any(x => x.email_add.Equals(email_add));
    if (obj)
    {
        tblUser user = db.tblUsers.Single(x => x.email_add == email_add);
        Session["email_add"] = user.email_add;
        Session["fname"] = user.fname;
        Session["lname"] = user.lname;
        return Json(new { result = "Redirect", Url = Url.Action("Check", "ProjectV3") });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new { result = "SingUp", Urls = Url.Action("SignUp", "ProjectV3", new { email_add = email_add}) });
    }
}
```

[This is i want to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVLcn.png)

Comment: You cant. How do you think the value would be sent to the server if its not in the url.

Comment: But the fact your returning a `JsonResult` suggest this is an ajax call so why not make it a POST and send it in the body?

Comment: Can you provide an example so that i can understand your point

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: your suggestion that make a post and send it to the body

Comment: Well I'm guessing that your calling this method by making an ajax call (otherwise returning a `JsonResult` would not make much sense). If that's the case, show the code for the ajax call.

Comment: i add my ajax in the top

Comment: The ajax code is already `type: "POST",` so all you need to do is decorate the method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute (and note its just `data: { email_add: email_add },` and remove the `contentType` option).

Comment: And as a side note, what your doing here is dreadful practice, and I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and learn the basics of authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to effectively hide something from the client Url you will need to find a way to either mask it, or store it somewhere on the server that can be captured on the next request.

There are many places you can store this data on your server but really the obvious ones are.

1. `Cookies`
2. [`TempData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx)

Now `TempData` may seem like the obvious choice as it persists across requests and is cleared from the `TempData` when accessed. Which is also its downfall, lets say you set the `TempData` in your `SingUpIn` method, then return the `JsonResul` which I am assuming is then used via JavaScript for a redirect. Then you redirect to this page and then pull the value of the `TempData` dictionary it is subsequently removed. So if the person ends up on the `SingUp` page and for some reasons decides to refresh the page the value in the `TempData` wont be found again.

Now this can be handled by resetting the TempData property on each read. So basically you read the `TempData` item then you reassign the `TempData` entry.

Here is some very basic code that [basically] works and doesnt show the email in the url.

```
public ActionResult SignUpIn(string email_acct)
{
    //pretend i tested for a real user
    TempData["email_acct"] = email_acct;
    var r = new { result = "SingUp", Urls = Url.Action("SingUp") };
    return Json(r);
}

public ActionResult SingUp()
{
    if (!TempData.ContainsKey("email_acct"))
    {
        //no temp data email.. maybe redirect.. who knows!!
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //read the temp data entry.. 
    string emailAcct = TempData["email_acct"].ToString();

    //reset the temp data entry
    TempData["email_acct"] = emailAcct;

    return View(new SingUpModel { EmailAccount = emailAcct });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to go to POST rather than URL parameters you are stuck. If you just want to hide some of the implementation details you could encode the parameter to obfuscate its meaning.

```
return Json(new { result = "SingUp", Urls = Url.Action("SignUp", "ProjectV3", new { email_add = Base64Encode(email_add)}) })
```

...

```
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
      var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
      return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
```

You would end up with a URL like: http://localhost:1126/ProjectV3/SignUp?email_add=cGtleWJpcmQ5NUBnbWFpbC5jb20=. You could obviously change the name of the parameter to hide its intent.

Comment: OP want to hide querystring

Comment: Yes and as people have said you can't, so i'm offering an alternative

Comment: It`s ok to decrypt the viewbag email because i want to make a form that can see the information and  can save in my data sql